# Group DataFrame by month and count values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new pandas user and I try to do something with my `DataFrame`.

I have `DataFrame` `watchers` with two columns: `repo_id` and `created_at`:

```
In: watchers.head()
Out:
            repo_id     created_at
    0       1           2010-05-12 06:16:00
    1       1           2009-02-16 12:51:54
    2       2           2011-02-09 03:53:14
    3       1           2010-09-01 09:05:21
    4       2           2009-03-04 09:44:56
```

I want to create new `DataFrame` - grouped by the month from `created_at` and `repo_id` and take information about count of rows for each of them. The result should be similar to:

```
In: watchers_by_month()
Out:
            repo_id     month                   count
    0       1           2009-02-28              32
    1       1           2009-03-31              42
    2       2           2009-05-31              3
    3       2           2009-06-30              24
    4       3           2013-04-30              23
```

The order doesn't matter. I just need to know `repo_id` still for each count.

I tried do something with my `DataFrame`, but I don't know how to achieve the above effect.

the only thing I could get:

```
In: watchers.index = watchers['created_at']
    watchers.groupby(['repo_id', pd.Grouper(freq='M')]).count()
Out:
                            created_at
    repo_id created_at  
    1       2009-02-28          323
            2009-03-31          56
            2009-04-30          29
            2009-05-31          24
            2009-06-30          35
    ...     ...                 ...
    107672  2013-04-30          6
            2013-05-31          3
            2013-06-30          3
            2013-07-31          6
            2013-08-31          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `watchers['created_at]` is of datetime64[ns], then create an additional `month` column

```
watchers['month'] = watchers['created_at'].dt.month

watchers_by_month = watchers.groupby(by=['repo_id','month']['created_at'].count().reset_index().rename_column(column={'created_at':'count'})
```

If your `watchers['created_at]` is not of datetime64[ns], then first convert `watchers['created_at]` to datetime64[ns] using `pd.to_datetime()` then create an additional `month` column , then run the above code.

Comment: Probably, my question lacked information that the year also matters. It doesn't matter - based on your answer, I also added a column with the year and the result is exactly what I expected. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, just turn that into a dataframe with `reset_index`:

```
(watchers.groupby(['repo_id', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])
         .count().reset_index(name='count')
)
```